# Why $|y|=|x||T^{-1}\rho(x)|<\varepsilon_k\delta_k$ where $2\delta_k \sup_{0\leq |x|\leq \varepsilon_k}|T^{-1}\rho(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

- Let $\varphi:U\to \mathbb R^n$ a $\mathcal C^1$ application where $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ open.
- Let $(\varepsilon_k)\subset \mathbb R^*_+$ a sequence of positif number s.t. $\varepsilon_k\to 0$ and denote  $$C_k:=\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid \|x-a_k\|_{\infty }\leq \frac{\varepsilon_k}{2}\},$$where $\displaystyle\|x\|_\infty :=\max_{i=1,...,n}|x_i|$
- Suppose $0\in C_k$ for all $k\geq 1$ and that $\varphi(0)=0$.
- Let $T:=\mathcal J_{\varphi}(0)$ the Jacobian matrix of $\varphi$ at $x=0$.

I'm trying to understand the proof of $$\liminf_{n\to \infty }\frac{m(\varphi(C_k))}{m(C_k)}\leq |\det T|,$$
where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb R^n$.

So we suppose $\det T\neq 0$. Then $$\varphi(x)=Tx+\|x\|_\infty \rho(x),$$
where $\|\rho(x)\|_\infty \to 0$ when $\|x\|_\infty \to 0$. Therefore $$T^{-1}\varphi(x)=x+\|x\|_\infty T^{-1}\rho(x).$$
Observe that $\|T^{-1}\rho(x)\|_\infty \to 0$ when $\|x\|_\infty \to 0$. Recall that $0\in C_k$, i.e. $\|a_k\|_\infty \leq \frac{\varepsilon_k}{2}.$ Therefore, if $x\in C_k$, then $$\|x\|_\infty \leq \|x-a_k\|_\infty +\|a_k\|_\infty \leq \frac{\varepsilon_k}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon_k}{2} =\varepsilon_k.$$
Therefore, if $x\in C_k$, then $$T^{-1}\varphi(x)=x+y,$$
where $$\|y\|_\infty =\|x\|_\infty \|T^{-1}\rho(x)\|_\infty <\varepsilon_k\delta_k,$$
where $$2\delta_k=\sup_{0\leq \|x\|_{\infty }\leq \varepsilon_k}\|T^{-1}\rho(x)\|_\infty .$$

This is what I don't understand :

**Question : For me $$\|y\|_{\infty }=\underbrace{\|x\|_\infty}_{\leq \varepsilon_k} \underbrace{\|T^{-1}\rho(x)\|_\infty}_{\leq 2\delta_k}\leq 2\varepsilon_k\delta_k,$$ So how do they get $\|y\|_\infty <\varepsilon_k\delta_k$ ? (i.e. the strict inequality and the upperbound $\varepsilon_k\delta_k$.)**

Comment: What are the $a_k?$ They seem to appear out of nowhere.

Comment: @zhw.: It's written in the hypothesis, $a_k$ is the center of the cube $C_k$, i.e. $C_k=\{x\in \mathbb R^n\mid \|x-a_k\|_\infty \leq \frac{\varepsilon_k}{2}\}$. (sorry if it was not clear)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }\frac{m(\varphi(C_k))}{m(C_k)}\le |\det T|?$$

Comment: @zhw. : Sorry it's not. It's really $\liminf$. Maybe it's a mistakes from the author ? But in an other way, this $\|y\|_\infty \leq \varepsilon_k\delta_k$ looks to make sense since if $A=\{x\mid \|x\|_\infty \leq \varepsilon_k\delta_k\}$ then $Diam(A)=\sup\{\|x-y\|\ : x,y\in A\}=2\delta_k\varepsilon_k$... what do you think ?

Comment: The end goal is to show

$$\lim_{k\to \infty }\frac{m(\varphi(C_k))}{m(C_k)}= |\det T|,$$

isn't it?

Comment: No, it's really to show $\liminf_{n\to \infty }\frac{m(\varphi(C_k))}{m(C_k)}\leq |\det T|$. The aim after is to show that $$m(\varphi(A))\leq \int |\det \varphi'|.$$